# the Object getter/setter vs new constructor - test results

Tags: javascript, object, setter, getter

I have a question.

**I hope you close this shit - many people are javascript-gods - but they write Ecmascript3 --

haha lol - If you dont understand what Object.create() do, then shut your mouth @LJ_1102!!!!**

I've done a test at jsperf.com, about two different ways for manipulation one object.

Please do not discuss with me about "object.create(p, pr)" and new Instance().

*Object.create() is the future and very simple for simple code.*

--->The question is not:  Need I a function and set prototypes and constructor or need I Object.create(prototype, new properties) <--- This is a question of faith

My question: **Why is there a big difference between the results in Chrome and Firefox?**

I know  - two different Javascript-engines. Yet why so different?

[--->link for testsite<---](http://jsperf.com/object-create-setter-getter-vs-new-constructor-function)

The test:

```
    var obj = {
    name: "",
    get getName(){return this.name;},
    set setName(x){this.name = x;}
    };

    function func(x){
    var that = this;
    this.name = ""; 
    this.getName = function(){return that.name;};
    this.setName = function(x){that.name = x;};
    }

    // Chrome:   1,536,214 ops/sec
    // Firefox:  302,952 ops/sec

          var newObj = Object.create(obj);
          obj.setName = "svenskanda";
          obj.getName;


    // Chrome:  315,572 ops/sec
    // Firefox: 1,360,496 ops/sec

          var newObj = new func();
          newObj.setName("Alex");
          newObj.getName();
```

In Chrome, the Object.create() - getter/setter is faster.

And in Firefox, the new-constructor method is faster.

Can you explain that?

Comment: your first test is invalid.

Comment: Note that the `obj` in the 1st example would be equivalent to using `func.prototype` for the 2nd. Embedding method definitions within the constructor will create new `Function` objects for `getName` and `setName` with every `new func`.

Comment: yes - that is okay - i will know what is the better way in time - and why is the same task so different?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be on codereview

Comment: oh thanks - i dont know from codereview :)

Comment: What exactly would you do if hypothetically someone would dig through both javascript engine source codes and tell you that chrome uses 1200 cpu cycles more for evaluating `new` statements and creates an internal object blueprint that is stored in RAM?

Comment: Then I would ask myself - why in such an important thing - as objects - Why it makes Firefox different - and who is right?

Comment: Then go ahead and ask *yourself*.

Comment: I have and then I ask you.

Comment: Neither one is right. Why do you think there's a right and wrong implementation? They are two different JS engines that have their own optimizations. If you built a JS engine, it would be much, much slower than both.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know *why* there's such a speed difference go check out the source, i'm afraid you wont find a chromium/firefox developer that also knows about the exact same internal code of the other project, and even if what would you do with that answer ?!

**They're two totally different javascript engines.**

Also you're doing two totally different things in your 'benchmark'.
`Object.create`s first argument is the *prototype* of the object to create, so all objects you create using `Object.create` share the **same** *name* property in your case. In your "constructor" benchmark you're constructing member methods with every construction of the object.

First learn to properly use prototypes and the associated methods, then write some code that actually suffers from a performance problem that is based on language performance, and then profile your code and find the bottlenecks.

Comment: my problem is not the prototype, as the different time - it does not matter what task i set - the point is: the same task in two big different times - you understand me  - and - The purpose of a test is the Different -

Comment: Read my answer again. You're not comparing "*the same task*"...

Comment: They're two totally different javascript engines -- This is an addendum -- edit by you  -- you understand me - Why does the browser do that? It's confusing for the user if the objects are faster in Chrome than Firefox. And the function objects in Firefox are faster than Chrome.

Comment: No i dont because both of your testcases are bad/non-sense. Also your question is like asking "why is linux booting faster than windows", yes totally confusing for the user but the answer will still be **because they're two totally different systems**

Comment: the test is okay - i get a new Object from Object.create how new Functionname

Comment: No because: all objects you create using Object.create **share** the **same** name property in your case.

Comment: <pre>
var obj1 = Object.create(obj);
console.dir(obj1);
ObjectgetName: (...)__proto__: Object 
var obj2 = Object.create(obj);
console.dir(obj2);
ObjectgetName: (...)name: "Svenskanda"__proto__: Object 
obj1.setName = "Alexander";
"Alexander"
obj2.setName = "Svenskanda";
"Svenskanda"
console.dir(obj1);
ObjectgetName: (...)name: "Alexander"__proto__: Object 
console.dir(obj2);
ObjectgetName: (...)name: "Svenskanda"__proto__: Object </pre>

Comment: var func1 = new func();
console.dir(func1);
funcgetName: function (){return that.name;}name: ""setName: function (x){that.name = x;}__proto__: func 
var func2 = new func();
func1.setName("svenskanda");
func2.setName("Alexander");
console.dir(func1);
funcgetName: function (){return that.name;}name: "svenskanda"setName: function (x){that.name = x;}__proto__: func 
console.dir(func2);
funcgetName: function (){return that.name;}name: "Alexander"setName: function (x){that.name = x;}__proto__: func